# Cloth simulation doesnt work

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am following a youtube tutorial, but the cloth simulation doesn't work as desire. May I know what the problem is? I have not idea what is going wrong

[image]

Comment: Which youtube tutorial?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uW5PasvZPFg&t=282s

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: You skipped the subdividing what you can see at 1:00. The cloth simulation use only existing verts, it won't create new ones so in your case just the four corner's location will be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The Blender cloth simulator will not work if you only have a simple un-subdivided mesh. If you go to edit-mode, and set the subdivision setting to around 50 subdivisions, then the simulation should work well. Setting the step quality of the cloth simulator to about 7 yields a fast simulation, while not using up too much RAM.